# select file browser is not working for input type file using Jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am facing one issue. The file select explorer is closing after 3 times click using jquery. I am explaining my code below.

**header.html:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.browse', function(){
    var file = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.file');
    file.trigger('click');
});
$(document).on('change', '.file', function(){
   $(this).parent().find('.form-control').val($(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''));
});
<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
<input type="file" name="logoimage" id="logoimage" ng-model= "form.logoimage" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadedImage(this);" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" class="file">
<div class="input-group col-xs-12">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Upload Logo" name="setlogoimage" id="setlogoimage" ng-model="setlogoimage">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="browse btn btn-primary" type="button">Upload File</button></span> 
</div>
</div>
```

The above is my header file which has one input type file functionality.

**audit.html:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.browsebtn', function(){
  var file1 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.filepath');
  file1.trigger('click');
  console.log('audit');
});
$(document).on('change', '.filepath', function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.form-control').val($(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''));
});
<div ng-include src="'header.html'"></div>
<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
<input type="file" ng-model="form.filencdoc" multiple name="ncevidencefile[]" class="filepath" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadedFile(this,4);">
 <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<input type="text" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 34px; padding: 6px 12px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.42857143; color: #555; background-color: #fff; background-image: none; border: 1px solid #ccc;" placeholder="Link to Evidences" ng-model="ncshowimp" id="ncshowimp">
 <span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="browsebtn btn btn-primary" type="button" style="border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0" id="browsbttn">Browse</button>
 </span>          
 </div>
</div>
```

Now let me explain the scenario. Lets say from the beginning user is in the **`header.html`** page  and click on some next button it redirected to **`audit.html`** page. Then when user come back to **`header.html`**  and select the input type file to select the file, the file explorer is opening but after 3 times click on **`cancel/select`** button it is closing which is my issue.

Usually it should close at one time click. Please help.

Comment: some errors in your browser console after you clicked 3 times?

Comment: @CodeNashor : No error but when I am clicking on browse button then this `$(document).on('click', '.browse', function(){
    var file = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.file');
    file.trigger('click');
});` function is executing 3(or multiple) times and this is only for my explained scenario.

Comment: Your script just working for opening file browser, right? If then you can apply another approach using 'label' tag with 'for' attribute to avoid any script. For both file you can set 'id' attribute in '.file'. Suppose like that: <input type="file" ng-model="form.filencdoc" multiple name="ncevidencefile[]" id="file" class="filepath" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadedFile(this,4);"> and then <label class="browsebtn btn btn-primary" for="file" style="border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0" id="browsbttn">Browse</label>.

Comment: How many times that 'audit' is logged in console?

Comment: @AsimKT : When user go to that audit page it logged at that time but not in other time.

Comment: I solved it using `e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.preventDefault();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `label` element instead doing hacky things.

https://codepen.io/asim-coder/pen/MryMJM

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="fileopen" name="fileopen">

<p>Some other things</p>

<label for="fileopen">styled button

</label>
```

CSS

```
label {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```